# Rails: Requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead.FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rmagick

When I create an object via FactoryGirl and Faker, shell show me an error

```
[1] pry(main)> FactoryGirl.create(:company)
[DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
```

but when I create object in development db - it's ok

there is factory

```
  factory :company do
    title Faker::Company.name
    image Faker::Avatar.image("my-own-slug", "200x200")
  end
```

how fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most certainly dues to CarrierWave when the execution comes to your line `image Faker::Avatar.image("my-own-slug", "200x200")`.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/1681) on CarrierWave which is closed now and the fix is merged. Either you include the github commit in your GemFile, or you wait for the next gem release.

Comment: The fix is not merged please checked the `lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb` in the master.

Comment: The fix is merged https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/commit/71cb18bba4a2078524d1ea683f267d3a97aa9bc8

Comment: the fix is merged but 0.11 is not yet released on rubygems but you can bundle it with:  
  
`gem "carrierwave", git: 'https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave.git', branch: '0.11-stable'`

Answer (score 4):

First, most people will want to include rmagick in their bundle like this:

```
gem 'rmagick', require: false
```

Second, rmagick 2.15.0 was just released. (Find your version with `bundle list`.) Upgrade the gem to version 2.15.0 with `bundle update`.

At this point you may *still* get the error as a pull request to remove it is [on github](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/1618) but has not been merged yet.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I didn't get this error :)

Answer (score 3):

This is very late however it might help someone:

```
gem 'carrierwave', :github => 'satoruk/carrierwave' , :ref => '43179f94d6a4e62f69e812f5082d6447c9138480'
gem 'rmagick', require: false
```

This should give you the version with rmagick fixed. I am not sure why they don't merge it to the master.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing the following in Gemfile:

```
gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'
```

try rewrite as follows:

```
gem 'rmagick'
```

https://github.com/gemhome/rmagick#installing-via-bundler

Answer (score 0):

Just update your *carrierwave* gem and that should do.

```
bundle update carrierwave
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same challenge when upgrading a **Rails 5** app to **Rails 6**

Here's how I fixed it:

First, I added the most recent version of the `rmagick` gem to the `Gemfile`. As of this writing it is **rmagick 4.2**:

```
gem 'rmagick', '~> 4.2'
```

Next, I checked for the files where rmagick has been required. I modified the file below from:

```
class Admin::FormPrecedentsController < Admin::BaseController

  require 'RMagick'

end
```

to this:

```
class Admin::FormPrecedentsController < Admin::BaseController

  require 'rmagick'

end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Carrierwave gem you had to try downgrading the version to 0.7.0, add on your gemfile 'carrierwave', '0.7.0' and then run on the console 'bundle update carrierwave'

Comment: Carrierwave has many breaking changes since 0.7.0, and advising people to perform a downgrade that would break their code, just to remove a warning message, is not a good thing.

Comment: When you are using a version of rails and ruby that it's not the most recent you have to take care about the versions on your gems, it would break your application if you use a old version along with new ones... and my solution solve the problem leaving the version working according the rails and ruby ate least on my case I bet to get the things working with the version that is on rather than apply an upgrade to all my environment

Comment: It may work for you, but it is not an acceptable "public" answer

Comment: If it's about compatibilty version I think it is an acceptable public answer that may could help to others on the same case

Comment: I'll stop entertaining this conversation. Please have a look at the changelog https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/History.md